# Static variable inside a function

Tags: c, memory-management

This is more of a theoretic question.
Say I have the following C program:

```
int a;
int f(){
    double b;
    static float c;
}
```

The question reads: For each of the variables (a, b, c), name the following: storage duration (lifetime), scope of identifier, the memory segment in which it is kept and its initial value.

As far as I've understood the theory so far:

**For the variable a**:

*lifetime*: static

*scope of identifier*: file level scope

*memory segment*: data segment

*initial value*: 0

**For the variable b**:

*lifetime*: automatic (local)

*scope level*: block level scope

*memory segment*: stack

*initial value*: undefined (random)

But the variable C is what confuses me.
As far as I understand its lifetime i static, its scope level is of block level scope, but I'm not sure about the memory segment or the initial value.

Usually, the local variables of a function are kept in the stack segment, but since the variable is static, should it then be kept in the data segment instead?

Comment: The C language doesn't have the concept of "segments". That is an implementation detail.

Comment: Well the question is from a C textbook

Comment: One way to figure out an implementation detail is to [consult an implementation](https://godbolt.org/g/hCJVZ1).

Comment: The scope of variable a is not restricted to the translation unit in which it is defined.  It has global scope.

Comment: *Well the question is from a C textbook* If the description of `a` is from that text book, the "*scope of identifier*: file level scope" is *wrong*.  As @WilliamPursell noted, `a` has *global* scope. Add in the other issues, I hope you didn't pay too much for it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Per C 2011 [N1570] 6.2.1 4, an identifier declared outside any block or list of parameter has *file scope*. “Global scope” is a colloquial term; “file scope” is the term actually used in the standard. It is also more precise, as the identifier is known within the translation unit (the file being translated [compiled], after preprocessing) and not globally to the entire program.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The **scope** of `a` is limited to the translation unit in which it is defined. It has external **linkage**, meaning that, if another identifier with the same name is declared in another translation unit, the two identifiers will be linked to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you don't need to deal with concepts like "segment", it depends on the file format(ELF, Mach-O, etc.).

A static variable, no matter where it is defined, their lifetime and initialization rules are the same. The only difference is the visibility of this symbol to compiler and linker. In your particular example, `static float c` is also zero initialized, just as `int a`.

And technically, if you are dealing with linux and ELF format, static variable without explicit initialization is put in .bss segment, not .data segment. .bss segment has no physical size in the file, but will be zero-initialized when the ELF file is loaded to execute.

You can use `nm` command to see the symbols in your file if you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a complement to you own analysis and @liliscent's answer. Variable `a` has *external* linkage, because it declared at file level with no *static* specifier. That means that it can be accessed from a different translation unit provided it is declared there as `extern int a;`. The other variables cannot be accessed from other translation units.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of segment can refer to 2 different things : 
Either the segments as seen by the CPU, which are references to a part of the memory pointed to by a segment register, Or a logical segment which is a name for some kind of data (as seen in assembler source code).

For an example, the .bss segment has no real existence. It only means : a part of the data segment which is initialized to zero and for this reason, doesn't need to be saved as data in the program file.

For the rest, one can assume there 3 kind of segments : Code, data and stack, with a special case for the heap, which is dynamically allocated in data segment, but this merely an implementation problem, which might vary according to the implementation.

However, for the purpose of simplification, one could consider as true that all static variables are allocated in the data segment, with just one specificity for data initialized to 0, which is in .bss (and thus, still in the data segment, but not imaged in the program file).

The only difference between global and local static, is it's visibility and its "name space" : you can have multiple static variables with the same name, local to different function and they will all be seen only in the function in which they were declared, but initialized at the beginning of the execution.

So on the contrary as automatic variables, which are allocated on the stack, each time the function is called - and thus, exists multiple times if the function is called recursively; static variable are shared by all simultaneous instances of the function. i.e. if a function calls itself and the called change the value of a static variable, the value will be changed for the caller too.